# How do I import a package defined in src/test directory from inside src/it

Tags: scala, testing, sbt

I have defined a class that I want to use both for normal unit and integration tests. These are currently located in `src/test` and `src/it`. I have defined this class in a package inside `src/test`. But I cannot figure out how to access it from inside tests defined in `src/it/.

build.sbt is like this:

```
...
  .configs(IntegrationTest)
  .settings(Defaults.itSettings)
...
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20683597/9204.

Comment: thanks, it is a duplicate. Couldn't find this post by myself. Again thanks for your help!